# Which int32 register content multiplied 42 gets the result 1?

Tags: c, assembly, cpu-registers

I'm trying to understand how to represent float value in int32 register `R0`.

I need to find the value of `R0` where `R0 * 42 = 1`

What value I can put into `R0` ?

I have been try put R0 `1/42` but it will be `0` because it's int.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What architecture are you programming for?

Comment: Do you literally mean "floating point", or do you just mean fractional or non-integer value in general?  If you want floating point, use floating point.  But then the multiply result won't be integer 1, it'll be an FP bit-pattern that represents `1`, and you can't use an integer multiply instruction.

Comment: I just looking for value to set on R0 (int32) to get R0 * 42 =1

Comment: Write a program to init such a var and either dump it's bytes in hex, or extract the bytes with a debugger.

Comment: The answer is `0x06186187`. Now you just need to figure what the question was.

Comment: @Yaron you cannot do that.  You can do 'R0 * 42.0 =1.0'.  In fact, user3386109 seems to have just done it:)

Comment: You keep writing `*`, but that's ambiguous. There are types of multiplication for which this question is answerable (actually an answer that works with a particular type of multiplication has already been given), and types of multiplication for which it is not. It would be much more useful to give the actual assembly instruction instead of a star sign, that way we would actually know what it does.

Comment: 42 doesn't have an inverse mod 2^32.

Comment: @user3386109 Please double check your value. The result of multiplying it by 42 (0x2a)  seems off by 0x25.

Comment: @Yunnosch that means you used the wrong kind of multiplication

Comment: @user3386109 why that value (0x06186187) ?

Comment: @hobbs: Indeed.  In particular, if `*` is integer multiplication then `R0 * 42` will always be an even number, even when accounting for overflow (mod 2^32) and so can never be `1`.

Comment: @NateEldredge I think you got a large part of what OP wants to know clarified. I recommend to make an answer. Also, I used your insight in mine (giving you credits). But I would happily upvote your reasoning why there is no answer to OPs question (and only claim coming up with the closes value and some explanation of the mechanisms for mine).

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking about is the multiplicative non-float inverse of 42 for a 32bit multiplication.
It would be the **integer** number which, if multiplied by 42 in a 32bit register would result in 1.
As Erik Eidt points out, this is not strictly a mathmatical inverse, more the effect of one, as exhibited by the modulo effect of an overflow.

Lets take a little detour to looking for a number which, if multiplied by 42 results in 2 in a 32bit register. That number is 0x3CF3CF3D. The result of 2 is caused by the truncation to 32bit, because 0x3CF3CF3D times 42 is 0xA00000002 and the "A" part is beyond 32bit. Note that 0x3CF3CF3D is odd, there is no integer half of it.

There is no such magic inverse number to result in 1 however, because any number multiplied by an even number like 42 cannot result in any odd number however big the part beyond 32bit might be. (credit to Nate Eldredge, who pointed this convincing observation out in a comment).

The same 0x3CF3CF3D multiplied by 21 results in 1 (actually in 0x500000001).
So for this odd number 21, the multiplicative inverse does exist, but not for 42.

Comment: Not a mathematical inverse, but an inverse modulo overflow.

Comment: @ErikEidt Good phrasing. Mind me using it in my answer?

Comment: Of course, help yourself!

Comment: @ErikEidt aka a "modular inverse", which is plenty mathematical :)

Comment: @hobbs, cool :) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse

Answer (score 0):

You could multiply the result by a number (i.e. 100) and then divide it before using it:

```
R0 = 1 * 100 / 42;
// later...
printf(".2f", R0 / 100.0f);
```

Comment: That would load '2'